# Django save() always create a new object

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have this model in my app which is meant to auto-generate it's primary Key based on a method added in the save().
However, for each object, I will be expected to make updates of certain fields. Right now, anytime I make an update on the admin side (testing use cases) it instead creates a new record of the PK instead of updating the existing one. Any thoughts on how to remedy this?

```
class DeploymentTask(models.Model):
    deployment_id = models.CharField(
        'Deployment Task ID', primary_key=True, max_length=25, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    current_status = FSMField('Current Status',
                              default=STATES[0], choices=STATES)
    site_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Site, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    refuel_record = models.ManyToManyField(RefuelRecord)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.deployment_id

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rm_deployment_task'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Deployment Tasks'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('deployment_id-view', args=[str(self.deployment_id)])

    def save(self):
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        ticket_count = DeploymentTask.objects.filter(
            created_at__year=today.year, created_at__month=today.month).count() + 1
        new_task_id = 'DPT-' + str(str(datetime.date.today().year)) + str(
            datetime.date.today().month).zfill(2) + str(
            datetime.date.today().day).zfill(2) + '-' + str(ticket_count).zfill(6)
        self.deployment_id = new_task_id
        super(DeploymentTask, self).save()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMbpv.png)

Comment: wrap the code for creating the `deployment_id` in a `if not self.pk`. That way, if the pk was already assigned, it won't recalculate it.

Comment: Note: It's a very bad idea to add `update_fields` to your `super()` call because that means you can never save any other field.

Comment: thanks for the input. I managed to fix it by not customizing the save() method and defining a function out of my model which will generate that id and assigning this method as a default one for my pk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my updated code, which worked for me...

```
def make_id():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    ticket_count = DeploymentTask.objects.filter(
                created_at__year=today.year, created_at__month=today.month).count() + 1
    new_task_id = 'DPT-' + str(str(datetime.date.today().year)) + str(
            datetime.date.today().month).zfill(2) + str(
            datetime.date.today().day).zfill(2) + '-' + str(ticket_count).zfill(6)  
    return new_task_id
class DeploymentTask(models.Model):
    deployment_id = models.CharField(
        'Deployment Task ID', primary_key=True, max_length=25, editable=False, default=make_id)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    current_status = FSMField('Current Status',
                              default=STATES[0], choices=STATES)
    site_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Site, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    refuel_record = models.ManyToManyField(RefuelRecord)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.deployment_id

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rm_deployment_task'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Deployment Tasks'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('deployment_id-view', args=[str(self.deployment_id)])
```

Answer (score 1):

- You are always setting `self.deployment_id` to a new value in the save method.
- Django tries to do `UPDATE ... WHERE deployment_id = %`, but there are no records with this id yet (at least if you are saving "old" object on different date or having different ticket_count)
- If you want to update fields other than `deployment_id`, then simply do not set `self.deployment_id` if it's already set. If you want to update `deployment_id` then there is not straightforward way to do this, because it's used as primary key (but you can remember old pk and delete that object after you have created a new one during `save`)

Read more in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert).

Comment: Hi Imposeren, thanks for the reply. The PK is meant to auto-generate based on the time of the day and the number of objects already in as you can see. When I modify by removing the "self."  new records are not creating but I can update old ones

Comment: I meant something like: `if not self.deployment_id: self.deployment_id = SOME_DT_BASED_STRING`. But your example with `default=make_id` does similar thing